# How to know which menu trigger a link?

Tags: menus

I have two menus locations in my WordPress self hosted Blog.  Both menu locations (`Header, Footer`) have the same menu items `Contact Us`. Now, when an user click this link. It will take him to the `contact us` page.

But I want to know which menu item triggered to reach the page. either Header or Footer.

Is there any code or function available in WordPress itself.

Comment: You could add url parameter on the menu url for example `?ref=footer` then process it on the contact us page to know the click was from footer link.

Comment: Just wondering why you would want something like this. ;-)

Comment: @Sisir, I added pages as menu. There is  no such a additional option to add menu url with it. its a page.

Comment: @PieterGoosen - From the beginning. without Thinking, i added this one in both menus.  Now I do want to remove one. So, I want to know which menu items get more users. So i can remove the less one.

Comment: You can not do it from UI. You will need to code it using php or js (will be an easier option).

Comment: Can you suggest me the steps to do.?